# libreoffice headless interprets source image as text

Tags: conversion, libreoffice

I am trying to use libreoffice to convert different source formats to pdf. This works with most formats but image formats are always interpreted as text:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export hdr1.jpeg
// console output: convert /home/dev/hdr1.jpeg -> /home/dev/hdr1.pdf using filter : writer_pdf_Export
```

The following libreoffice verison is installed (Ubuntu 20.04):

```
libreoffice --version
LibreOffice 6.4.7.2 40(Build:2)
```

The resulting file `hdr1.pdf` does not contain the image but its binary data interpreted as text. I also tried the same with `unoconv` which results in the same problem.

Is there a special flag required to make libreoffice interpret images as images and not as text?

Regards,

Comment: I have added the libreoffice version.

Comment: And the output of `file hdr1.jpeg`. To see what the system thinks that file is.

Comment: It returns ``hdr1.jpeg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 72x72, segment length 16, Exif Standard: [TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=10, manufacturer=Canon, model=Canon EOS 350D DIGITAL, orientation=upper-left, xresolution=164, yresolution=172, resolutionunit=2, software=easyHDR PRO 2.11.1beta16, datetime=2011:06:14 15:10:42], baseline, precision 8, 870x580, components 3``.

Comment: You could try running `lodraw` instead of `libreoffice`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Installing ``libreoffice-draw`` fixed the problem. Now the command works.

Comment: @Eduardo Trápani, if you post your reply as an answer then I can set is as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks @Hyndrix, I just did. I added a bit more information so that it can be more broad and maybe help other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libreoffice` is a suite of applications. When executed with a file as a parameter, it will try to guess the type of file and open the corresponding application:

```
   lobase
   localc
   lodraw
   lofromtemplate
   loimpress
   lomath
   loweb
   lowriter
```

If the application is not there, then it might default to `lowriter`.

Check if you have the libre-office application  you want to use and install it if you do not.

```
$ lodraw
```

or

```
$ libreoffice --draw
```

if it is not found you can do the following in Debian/Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libreoffice-draw
```